# How to use heavyweight post with Jenkins declarative pipeline while running pipeline on lightweight executor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline that looks like follows:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent any
      steps { ... }
    }
    stage('Tests') {
       parallel {
         stages { ...}
    }
 }
 post {
   cleanup {
      node {
         [something heavyweight]
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is that I can't determine how to wrap the `[something heavyweight]`. I'm trying to follow best practices by running the pipeline on a lightweight executor. I think an alternative would be a stage before post that ran on a heavyweight executor that could carry out the cleanup actions. But then I'd need some way for it to figure out the overall pass/fail of the pipeline. . .which is unknown until you actually get to the final post!

Answer (score 0):

My current solution was to create a Jenkins slave on the master with label 'PIPELINE', configure it to only run jobs with that label, then use that label with the top level agent in the pipeline. It's a bit annoying because the job will always start with a lightweight executor on the master anyway, but I think this keeps resources down to execute the pipeline while leaving the true heavyweight executors available.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'PIPELINE' }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      agent any
      steps { ... }
    }
    stage('Tests') {
       parallel {
         stages { ...}
    }
 }
 post {
   cleanup {
      node {
         [something heavyweight]
      }
   }
}
```